# Extremely simple -- how to compare chars

Tags: objective-c

I shouldn't be struggling this much. I want to extract a character from a string and compare it to a char. Here's the offending line:

```
if ([url characterAtIndex:url.length - 4] == "=") {
    NSString *test = [url substringFromIndex:url.length - 3];
    return [test intValue];
} else {
    NSString *test = [url substringFromIndex:url.length - 2];
    return [test intValue];
}
```

On the if line it throws the error `Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'char *')`, strange enough on it's own since there isn't a single int in that comparison.

A second error also pops, `Result of comparison against string literal is unspecified (use strncmp instead)`.

I'd love help with this error, I have no idea why it's getting thrown and it's stopping me from getting to the real work of debugging network calls. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `"="` to `'='`.

`"="` is a C string.

`'='` is a char.

BTW - `characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar` which is an `unsigned short`.

Comment: Can't accept answers for another 12 minutes, but thank you! What a simple thing to have cause this much frustration in an if loop.